# Wrong answer key in Thomas' Calculus 14th edition?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

The below exercise is from the textbook I'm reading and I think the answer given at the back of the book is wrong.

> Integrate
> $$
> \iint_R xydxdy
> $$
> where $R$ is the region bounded by $x=2a$ and $x^2=4ay$.

for which the solution is given as $a^4/15.$

**Solution**
I'm assuming the region $R$ is bounded by the *coordinate axes* and the given curves. Therefore, the integral becomes
$$
\int_0^a\int_{2\sqrt{ay}}^{2a}xydxdy=\int_0^{2a}\int_0^{\frac{x^2}{4a}} xydydx
$$

which upon evaluation yields $a^4/3$. Is it possible that I've missed something?

Comment: You are not missing anything. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumptions of the coordinate axis, just doing it the other way around from you,
$$
\int\int xy dx dy=\int \frac{x^2}2\biggr|_\sqrt{4ay}^{4a}ydy\\
=2a\int_0^a(ay-y^2)dy\\
=2a(\frac12ay^2-\frac13y^3)\biggr|_0^a\\
=\frac13a^4 
$$

Also, regardless of assumptions about the limits of the integration, there definitely isn't any factor of $1/5$ which arises from this problem, so the book's answer seems to come out of nowhere.